# Laravel : I received song file "form-data" from one of API then i need to forward that file to another API. Any idea to forward?

Tags: laravel

Laravel project 1 controller how to forward file to API-2

[image: v]

```
Input::file('songFile')->move("/tmp", $newname);
```

i used this function and store tmp location then how to use this tmp location file and forward?

Comment: call that api using guzzle

Comment: yes, use GuzzleHttp\Client; @bhucho

Comment: You were asking for a idea, I gave an idea, I guess you didn't ask for a solution

Comment: I am using guzzle. But i asked how to transfer a file one api to another api. That is my question? @bhucho

Comment: When i hit first api the file was store "tmp" location then how to post second api that file? @bhucho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to post a file to API endpoint, you can follow the following code.

```
try{
$path = 'var/www/html/myproject/public/file.txt';//your file path
if (!empty($path) && file_exists($path)) {

   $guzzleResponse = $client->post($api_url, [
       'multipart' => [
                        [
                            'name' => 'file',// it is the name as specfied in the payload of api_url
                            'contents' => fopen($path, 'r')// or you can use file_get_contents()
                        ]
                    ],
                    'headers' => $headers
       ]);
}
if ($guzzleResponse->getStatusCode() == 200) {
   $response = json_decode($guzzleResponse->getBody());// whatever you want to do with response
}
}catch(RequestException $e){
    return $e;  //You can also handle specific status codes here using eg $e->getResponse()->getStatusCode() == '400'
}
```

Also $headers can be like this

```
[
     'Accept'                => 'application/json',
     'Authorization'         => 'Bearer '. $userToken,
]
```

See more information in [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#multipart)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's working fine. I used "test.mp3" file. But finally received file format is wrong. It's seems like "phpTVaLQf". File size is correct. @bhucho

Comment: Do you have any solution.

Comment: you are only transferring your mp3 file or there are other contents as well

Comment: what did you changed? I was about to suggest to about sink(if you were only transferring your mp3 file ) http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#sink